# Getting a value from XML response in REST-Assured

Tags: java, xml-parsing, rest-assured

I'm trying to get a value from an XML response using [REST Assured](http://rest-assured.io/), but I'm only getting empty values.

XML example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ncresponse
    orderID="50143601"
    STATUS="5"
    SCORING="1"
    SCO_CATEGORY="G">
</ncresponse>
```

My code:

```java
RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
Map<String, String> body = new HashMap<>();
body.put("ORDERID", orderId);
body.put("USERID", QUERY.getUser());
body.put("PSW", QUERY.getPass());
Response validation = given().proxy(host("myproxy.com").withPort(8080)
    ).params(body).when().get(QUERY.getUrl());

return from(validation.asString()).get("ncresponse.STATUS");
```

In this case, I'm trying to get the `STATUS` value ("5"), but all I'm getting is `""` for any attribute.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Well, i realized that I was making a mistake here. I was trying to get an attribute from the node "ncresponse", so using "@" symbol before the attribute is neccesary:

```
from(validation.asString()).get("ncresponse.@STATUS");
```

Im closing this, thanks for all!

Answer (score 2):

You need to first convert the response to xml type and then get the value from that response.

First you need to import the following in your code:

`import io.restassured.path.xml.XmlPath;`

And then your code should be:

```
String stringResponse = validation.asString();
XmlPath xmlPath = new XmlPath(stringResponse);
String status = xmlPath.get("ncresponse.STATUS");
```

Now the String `status` contains the value which you want.